# How to break a for loop before it finishes going through all of its iterations Godot gdscript

Tags: for-loop, godot, gdscript

I am having an issue with my for loop in godot and hopefully you can help please!

For my game inventory system, I am using a `for` loop to update the quantity of items in the inventory. For example, if I fire an arrow, the `for` loop will loop through all the inventory slots, find one with arrows and reduce the amount by one, as shown here:

```
    for slot in range(0, inventory_maxSlots):
        
        if (inventory[String(slot)]["id"] == String(item)):
            var newAmount = inventory[String(slot)]["amount"] - 1
            if (newAmount == 0):
                inventory_updateItem(slot, 0, 0)
                update_slot(slot)
            else:
                inventory[str(slot)] = {"id": str(item), "amount": int(newAmount)}
                update_slot(slot)
```

This works perfectly except for when I have stacks of arrows in more than one slot. If I have 3 slots filled with 10 arrows each, for example, after firing 1 arrow, all stacks will be reduced by 3. So I will end up with 3 stacks of 7 arrows. If I had 4 stacks of arrows, then each get reduced by 4 etc.

I just want the loop to start, find the first slot with arrows, reduce its amount by 1 and then stop. I tried using a `Break` but it only seemed to stop the loop once it had run through all of the slots, and not just the first slot with arrows it finds.

I am only a couple of months into learning programming so I have probably missed something really obvious and I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Comment: Your title is very generic. Could you change it to a question that is more specific?

Comment: I hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: Break would stop the loop, where do you put it? Also, what does `update_slot()` do?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. update_slot() is a function which just updates the display of the item icon and stack number in the inventory slot. It doesn't actually change what is there, just its display. I have tried it by putting 2 breaks, after the update_slot() function. One at the end of the If statement and one at the end of else. The problem is that the new amount is getting passed multiple times when I only want it to happen once.

Comment: If I have 1 stack of arrows it works perfectly, but each additional stack of arrows will then subtract the 'newAmount' variable an additional time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help on this one and I have solved it now. You were correct a Break was exactly what was needed. The problem was that I had another for loop earlier in the code which I also needed to add a break to. Thanks again!